# Removing enum values from mysql column

Tags: mysql, enums, alter

I have a table with a enum column called `action`. The permitted values currently are:
`act1,act2,act3,act4`. I want `act3` and `act4` to be removed and my table's current state does not contain any rows with `act3` or `act4`.

When I'm trying to modify the column with the new set of values it's throwing an error
`Data Truncated for column action`.

Please suggest how do I remove the required values.

Comment: Maybe don't use enum at all? http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: Show your CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `ALTER TABLE` for adding enum values is ok and described in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

However, for removing enum values the better option is to create a new column to do the change.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD new_action_column ENUM('act1', 'act2') ... ;
UPDATE your_table SET new_action_column = action;
ALTER TABLE your_table DROP action;
ALTER TABLE your_table CHANGE new_action_column action ENUM('act1', 'act2') ... ;
```

---

**Edit**

By the way. Using `ENUM` is not the best idea, you should use `INT` instead.

[8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)

I suggest you to use a mapping like

```
+------+-----+
| ENUM | INT |
+======+=====+
| act1 |  0  |
+------+-----+
| act2 |  1  |
+------+-----+
```

Comment: "you should use INT instead." - Why?

Comment: @Barmar [8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) Tombom already mentioned it. I suggest to use a mapping between your enum values 'act1' and 'act2' and int values 0, 1.

Comment: @FlorianParain I wonder why there should be any advantageous not altering the existing column but rather adding a temporary one. Can you reason your statement? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First run a query.

```
UPDATE table_name SET action = '' WHERE action IN ( 'act3', 'act4' );
```

after this run this query.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE action action ENUM( 'act1', 'act2' );
```

there is no need to drop your table or drop your field. but you are required to delete or update all data having the values, which you want to remove.

Comment: He said there aren't any rows with the values he's going to remove.

Comment: I am not required to make the above steps as my table does not contain rows with 'act3' and 'act4'. The error is still there.

Answer (score 3):

The other two answers already covered the question in larger detail, but here is a simple issue why *you* may not be able to simply do ALTER TABLE. If you have an ENUM('BAR','FOO','REMOVEME') and it gives an Error saying something along the lines of Data truncated somethingsomething, you might already have an entry set to the very Enum member you want to remove. So you'd first need to do something like

> UPDATE yourtable SET enumrow='FOO' WHERE yourenumrow = 'REMOVEME';

This way, all entries that had REMOVEME will now be FOO and the table can be altered using

> ALTER TABLE yourtable CHANGE yourenumrow yourenumrow ENUM('FOO','BAR') DEFAULT NULL;